# How to create a `inline` table that refers to other tables in QlikView?

Tags: database, qlikview

For a training I would like to create a table **Data** and  two related tables (**A_Left**, **A_Right**) in [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview). Using a database  that works very well, but how can I do that `inline`?

(The idea is to work without a database to copy the comple script to SE for example.)

```
A_Left:
Load a_id_left,
     a_name_left
inline [
  a_id_left, a_name_left
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
];

A_Rigtht:
Load a_id_right,
     a_name_right
inline  [
  a_id_right, a_name_right
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
];

Data:
Load id, 
     a_id_left,
     a_name_left as 'Name_Left',
     a_id_right,
     a_name_right as 'Name_Right',
     data
inline [
  id, a_id_left, a_right_id, data
  1, 1, 2, 37
  1, 1, 3, 18
  1, 2, 3, 62
];
```

Thanks for help an ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This script is very close to doing what you want I think. In the load syntax before inline, you cannot reference a column not defined in the following inline (they'll join by and function based on the relations). Also, you had a minor typo on one of the id's.

```
A_Left:
Load a_id_left,
     a_name_left
inline [
  a_id_left, a_name_left
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
];

A_Rigtht:
Load a_id_right,
     a_name_right
inline  [
  a_id_right, a_name_right
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
];

Data:
Load id, 
     a_id_left,
     a_id_right,
     data
inline [
  id, a_id_left, a_id_right, data
  1, 1, 2, 37
  1, 1, 3, 18
  1, 2, 3, 62
];
```

*You could have also meant to create a resident memory table by this post but I guessing that is not needed in this case; most of QlikView can just use the structure as defined above.